# tips on hmac function, for login

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication, hmac

Hi all i am working on putting together a new login system for my database which will hopeful be more secure than my old  md5 password encryption page.. 
i am just wondering if i could get some tips on this bit of code i am going to be going to use for it... mainly if there are anythings i can or should do to improve the security on this part... Many thanks...

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$user'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$salt=$rows['salt'];
$site_key=$rows['site_key'];
}

      function hash_password($salt,$pass,$site_key) {
  global $site_key;
  return hash_hmac('sha512',$pass . $salt, $site_key);
}
$password=hash_password();
$hashed= mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

Comment: Don't use globals; besides, hash_hmac is the wrong tool for the job anyway.

Comment: @Jack: What's wrong with `hash_hmac`?

Comment: @minitech I'm not saying there's anything wrong with it; the reason I'm saying that is because IMHO it's easier to use bcrypt than it is to keep `$site_key` secret:)

Comment: Use [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/password_verify) for passwords. Use PDO or MySQLi to [prevent SQLi](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide).

Answer (score 0):

I hope `$user` has been escaped? Anyway, switch to PDO or MySQLi instead of using `mysql_`.

As for hashing passwords, don't just use SHA-512 or something like that; those can be computed too quickly. I would recommend bcrypt:

```
function hash_password($password, $salt) {
    return crypt($password, '$2y$11$' . $salt);
}
```

Comment: to use mysqli will i need to be running a mysqli server... and i also am unfirmillar with PDO's.... Yes the $user varible was escaped

Comment: @Matthew time to get familiar with PDO then, because `mysql_` is being removed soon.

Comment: what would be the best site to begin to get fimallir with pdo's

Comment: @Matthew: No, you don't need a special server to use MySQLi or PDO, as long as the extensions are enabled (which they should be just about anywhere). I found http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/ a helpful introduction to PDO.

Answer (score 0):

`$sql="SELECT * FROM`users`WHERE username='$user'";` This part is open to SQL injection. Use something like PDO or MySQLi

Comment: how would i change it to mysqli.. i am not aprticluary fimallair with it